# Error while linking after modifications on ocaml compiler's code

Tags: compilation, ocaml

I was tweaking source code of OCaml(current `trunk` branch) to dump some type information into `json` . The first thing I need is to get the in-memory type data structure of `type_expr`. As in OCaml's official toplevel, it uses `Printtyp.tree_of_type_scheme exp.exp_type` to get the find type(generating type variable names) of an expression in file `toplevel/toploop.ml`(https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/toplevel/toploop.ml#L252).

While I try to use `Printtyp` inside `typing/printtyped.ml` in its simplest form:

```ml
let tree_of_type_expr (typ : Types.type_expr) =
  Printtyp.tree_of_type_scheme typ
;;
```

The build fails saying that it can not find `Printtyp`. Here is the log:

```
boot/ocamlrun boot/ocamlc -nostdlib -I boot  -compat-32 -o ocamlc \
   compilerlibs/ocamlcommon.cma compilerlibs/ocamlbytecomp.cma driver/main.cmo
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while linking compilerlibs/ocamlcommon.cma(Printtyped):
Reference to undefined global `Printtyp'
```

So I was wondering did I miss something about using `Printtyp`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to update the .depend file so that it takes the new dependency in mind while ordering the files for compiling. A `make depend` has to be done after any modification on your modules.

EDIT:
The linking order is defined directly in the makefile, depend only makes sure the files are compiled in the right order.

So you need to dig up `Makefile` and rearrange the order between your two files, in current trunk on github that would be line 57 and 58 (for future people, in the definition of `TYPING`)

Comment: jHi, @PatJ, thanks for the advice. I tried `make depend` and it did update the `.depend` file saying that `Printtyped` depends on `Printtyp`. While a following `make world.opt` still fails with the same error, it's been tested bother in Mac OS 10.10.2 and ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you tried `make clean` ? I'm not sure that the depend does mark the files as to be recompiled. Also, seeing the commands generated to compile and link printtyp*.cm* and ocamlcommon.cma would probably help.

Comment: I did tried `make clean`. And it's the same error.More over,  1. the ocamlcommon.cma was generated. 2. I also use `ocamlobjinfo` to see whether ocamlcommon.cma contains the Printtyp module and it does.  The command failed last was `boot/ocamlrun boot/ocamlc -nostdlib -I boot  -compat-32 -o ocamlc compilerlibs/ocamlcommon.cma compilerlibs/ocamlbytecomp.cma driver/main.cmo`. But `ocamlcommon/cma` does contain `Printtyp`, what could be possible causes?

Comment: As stated in the last edit, it does contain the module but it is after `Printtyped`, which makes it "undefined" when trying to link `Printtyped`.